# Non-iterative deterministic function to map an input to a random output in range without repeating

Tags: functions, random, random-functions

Apologies if this has been answered before or is impossible, but:

Is there a state-independent, non-iterative function that, given an (integer) input (n) and (integer) minimum (min) and maximum (max) values, uniquely maps *n* to a pseudorandom (integer) output between *min* and *max*?

By non-iterative, I mean it wouldn't have to iterate through every number in the set from *min* to *max* in order to map *n*.

For example (I do not know LaTeX, sorry):

The function is defined as f(n, min, max)

```
f(1, 1, 5) = 5
f(2, 1, 5) = 2
f(3, 1, 5) = 4
f(4, 1, 5) = 1
and f(5, 1, 5) = 3
```

And similarly for other *min* and *max* values.